# Webpack html-loader is breaking my HTML template files

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader

The webpack html-loader breaks my html files by putting a 'module.exports' at the front of the html file.

```
module.exports = "<div> my html </div>"
```

I can't have this in my site.

Is there any way around this?

Weirdly, if I use the webpack dev-server this 'module.exports' does not appear, it is only when I publish it live.

my html loader is set up like this :

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          attrs: [':data-src']
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share any portions of your webpack.config file that have to do with either this loader or *.html files?

Comment: added it to the question